# Calculating value represented by hexadecimal floating-point numeral

Tags: c, floating-point, hex

Can someone explain how we calculate the value of Hexadecimal Floating point constant.
I was reading a book and found 0x0.3p10 represents the value 192.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponent is still expressed in decimal, but the base is two, and the mantissa is in hex.

So 0.3P10 is (3 × 16<sup>−1</sup>) × 2<sup>10</sup>, which is 3/16 × 2<sup>10</sup>, which is 3 × 2<sup>6</sup> = 192.

Each hex digit of the mantissa gobbles up four units of exponent, since 16 = 2<sup>4</sup>.

Comment: i got clear about exponent part. have some doubt in mantissa part. can you tell me how we will calculate if it will be 0x3.3P10

Comment: Sure: It's (3 * 1 + 3 / 16) * 2^10.

Comment: why you have wrote it (3*1)? will it not be ((3/16)+(3/16)) * 2^10 or (3.3/16)*2^10

Comment: @Aadietya Remember that the "." in the mantissa is a hexadecimal point, not a decimal point.

Comment: @Aadietya: Did you know, that 16^0 == 1 and "/ 16" is the same as "* 16^(-1)" ?

Comment: The preferred term is “significand”, not “mantissa”. Significands are linear. Mantissas are logarithmic.

Comment: Why is the exponent in base 10?  That is so confusing.  Is it part of the standard?  It's like someone explaining their standard: "3.3e10 isn't 33 billion because we made the exponent to be in base 9, lol!"